# Доступ к файлам в папке \Windows\System32\drivers

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Пытаюсь удалить файл C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys

Получаю ошибку: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys'

Понимаю, что дело в правах, пару дней борюсь, к гуглу обращался.

**Пробовал:**

1. Через `os.remove`:

```
os.remove('C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys')
```

2. Пробовал через `os.system` и cmd:

```
os.system('del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys')
```

с двойными кавычками и без.

3. Пробовал запустить консоль python.exe от имени администратора, в безопасном режиме Windows и вручную вводить:

```
os.system('del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys)
```

4. Пробовал сделать exe из программы (cx_Freeze) так же запустить в безопасном режиме и от имени администратора.

При этом запуская в cmd:

```
del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys
```

Файл отлично находится и удаляется.

Мой вопрос: как удалить файл (в примере BdBoot.sys) средствами Python?

Comment: У вас не закрыта кавычка.

Comment: Подскажите где не закрыта кавычка, т.е. скопируйте пример и добавьте кавычку (если вы про `os.system('del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys)`, там моя опечатка, что её нет. Python не дал бы запустить команду без кавычки)

Comment: `os.system('del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys')`

Comment: Я про это и написал, там моя опечатка в оригинальной команде конечно же кавычка есть.  
Python не дал бы запустить команду без кавычки.
Моя проблема что команды запускаются, но файл не находится.
Даже если я напишу: `os.system('del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys')` или даже  `os.system('"del %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\BdBoot.sys"')`

Comment: Возможно тут имеет место Wow64 редирект. Убедитесь, что биность интерпретатора соответствующая.

Comment: Но разве использование указания не прямого пути %SystemRoot% не решает эту проблему?

Comment: Редиректится содержимое папки System32

Comment: Попробуйте через `r`-строки.

Comment: @user7860670 О! Проблема действительно в Wow64 редиректе. Скачал 64 битную консоль Python файл удалился. А как быть, если программа будет запускаться на 32х и 64х системах?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, проблема не в r - строке, я пробовал и так, проблему описали выше это Wow64.

Comment: [Disable File System Redirector](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578035-disable-file-system-redirector/)

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо, нашел эту же статью и изучаю! 
Видимо у меня не хватает прав проголосовать за лучший ответ, но у кого хватит, проголосуйте за ответ "Wow64" - это причина проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут имеет место перенаправление WOW64 - при попытке получить доступ к папке "Windows/System32" 32-битные приложения на самом деле получают доступ к папке "Windows/SysWOW64".

Как вариант, можно попробовать временно отключить перенаправление для текущего процесса:

```
import ctypes

class disable_file_system_redirection:
    _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
    _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
        self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.success:
            self._revert(self.old_value)


#Example usage
import os

path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\msg.exe'

print os.path.exists(path)
with disable_file_system_redirection():
    print (os.path.exists(path))
print (os.path.exists(path))
```